# Some API calls get failed when i make multiple calls(around 12) using Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise, axios, es6-promise

I want to make multiple API call. number of calls is 12,i am using Promise.all method. but problem is some calls get failed. number of failed calls is not fixed. it's sometimes 4 or some times 2 or 6.
but it works fine when i use to make only 5 calls.
can anyone help what's the problem. 
Here goes my code:

```
const getReturnData = async (item) => {
        const res = await axios.get(`${BASE_URLS.signupBaseUrl}/mutual-funds/nav/${item}`)
        return res;
    }

    const sample = ['call1', 'call2', 'call3', 'call4', 'call5', 'call6', 'call7', 'call8', 'call9', 'call10', 'call11', 'call12']

    useEffect(() => {
        let promises = sample.map(item => {return getReturnData(item)})

        axios.all(promises).then(values => {
            setReturnData(values.map(item => item));
        }).catch(err => {
            setReturnData([])
            throw err
        })
    },[])
```

Comment: Failed how? You are catching an error? What is the error details? Does the server rate-limit requests or similar?

Comment: yes, i am catching an error 500, but requsets go fine when number of calls is less, around 4 or 5

Comment: a 500 is your server unable to handle the request load. not an issue your javascript

Comment: "*an error 500, status code: 429*", wait, which one of the two?

Comment: nevermind, it's error 500

Comment: If you Google 429, it is thrown when there are too many requests on the server to secure it from crashing. Either don't make so many requests at once or talk to your server admin to allow them.

Comment: If it is 500, then it has nothing to do with client-side, multiple requests may be the reason for it, but it's fixed need to be done at your backend.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Promise.all() will fail if there is a reject() call during iterating the promise objects.

Here is a quick example

```
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    reject("p1");
  }, 100);
});
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("p2");
  }, 100);
});
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("p3");
  }, 100);
}); 

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(response=> { 
  console.log("Success", response);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Fail", err);
})
```

The console log of above would be "Fail, p1" because there is an exception among the Promise objects.

So you need to catch the API call's exception individually in order to make all API requests.

```
const getReturnData = (item) => {
      return axios.get(`${BASE_URLS.signupBaseUrl}/mutual-funds/nav/${item}`).then(response => { return response; }).catch(err => { //handle error here });
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not used to async-await but this should work

```
 const sample = ['call1', 'call2', 'call3', 'call4', 'call5', 'call6', 'call7', 'call8', 'call9', 'call10', 'call11', 'call12']

  useEffect(() => {
    let promises = sample.map(item => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const res = axios.get(`${BASE_URLS.signupBaseUrl}/mutual-funds/nav/${item}`)
          resolve(res)
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      })

    })

    Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
      setReturnData(values.map(item => item));
    }).catch(err => {
      setReturnData([])
      throw err
    })
  }, [])
```